# Android Studio - Can't click and edit in design mode

Tags: android-studio

I can't click and edit the items from palette when it's in design mode. If i double click, it goes to something else but regardless, I can't click and move around items in the design mode.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug report for Android Studio, not like a real programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using Relative Layout.

I'll suggest you to go to Text Mode of coding instead of design mode first. IMO that's easier when it comes to adjust things around.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:text="ButtonTest" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ok so now you to adjust position of your views that you have added here. You can use attributes like:
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to put that view in center of layout horizontally`

Similarly, use `android:layout_below="@+id/somethingElse"` to adjust the view below it.
You can manually type the margins this way instead of adjusting it with mouse by dragging.
The code is generally created automatically once you create a view like button or anything else in design mode. You just need to add attributes like that.

And just incase you want to use dragging method only, I strongly recommend you to switch to RelativeLayout and use text mode. There is Preview tab on the right side. You can try Dragging from there. It works for from there. Let me know your outcome.

**EDIT: Just make your layout to Relative Layout.**

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. All I need is to be able to click and move things

Comment: OK let me explain . But before that could you please add your XML code that you are coding now in your question . And also let me know how you want to adjust them. So I can help you learn it

Comment: All I did was place something from palette. I don't have any code. I can't move around objects

Comment: The code is generated automatically when you add something from the palette. Click on the TEXT option beside the DESIGN tab and copy paste that code in your question. Let me know how you want to adjust it so I can help you learn.

Comment: @Sarujan cool, can you see that `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout` both at start and end of file? Replace this whole thing with `RelativeLayout` and then try

Comment: I mean `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout`. This is there in your code that you shown me right?? Remove `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout` and type `RelativeLayout` instead of that then dragging will work.

Comment: @Sarujan see this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/0iNfmp8.png)

Comment: It's honestly not dragging, the code is red squiggly. Thank you for your help. I will continue to troubleshoot

Comment: @Sarujan the red thing is issue from your code. Please try adding basic elements like Button or TextView and try dragging. Try restarting Android Studio.

Comment: Just for future purposes. Why did it change?

Comment: @Sarujan Glad you can work now :-) Hope you liked the answer

Comment: @Sarujan There are various types of layouts in Android Studio. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout[default], etc. They all work differently. As the name states, in RelativeLayout the elements are placed in positons with respect to other elemetns. In constraint layout it's difficult because you need to add parameter or checj postions form all side. So its my suggestion whenever you use Android Studio, it's easier to use Relative layout for basic needs :-)

Comment: @Sarujan if your problem is solved , you can accept it by ticking the tick icon to let others know its solved.